# Static array in C

Tags: c, arrays, variable-length-array

I always knew that it was not possible to build a dynamic array in C without using `malloc` and `free`, so why is this code compiling and running correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Insert a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    int array[a];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand();
    }

    for(i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", array[i]);
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that this is not a really dynamic array since there is no way to change the size of "array" after it has been declared, nor it can be freed callling `free()` but still I always thought that the size of static array must be known at compile time which is clearly not the case here..

Comment: It is known as a VLA(Variable Length Array). It was introduced in C99

Comment: What makes you think it is a static array? I can't see the "static" keyword anywhere. And the "things you always knew" are not always the things that are true, as explained by Cool Guy.

Comment: as far as I know "static array" means an array which is allocated before the execution of the main(), which is the case of every fixed-sized array you use in your code

Comment: @user2318607 : The array `array[]` is not allocated *before* main is executed, and it is not the case for *every fixed-sized array*.  The `static` storage class specifier is not the *opposite* of *dynamic*.  In this case `array[]` has `auto` storage class - it is allocated on the stack on entry to the function in which it is placed.  In this case, because it is in the function `main()` it just happens to have a *similar* lifetime to a `static`.

Comment: if i declare in a function a local variable like int a[5], isn't it allocated before execution on the stack and stays there for the whole lifetime of the process? this is what I mean with static array

Comment: No.  That function with `int a[5]` may never get called or it may recurse needing multiple `int a[5]`.  The space is allocated at run time.

Comment: @CoolGuy : You really should post answers as answers rather than comments.  That is clearly an answer.

Comment: @Clifford ,I've already posted it....In the duplicate post!

Comment: @CoolGuy Fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using is [variable length array](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). Which is supported by C99 and latter. But note that VLA has automatic storage duration unlike dynamic memory allocated by `malloc` family functions.

Also note that compile time allocation is not equivalent to `static` array. `static` array and static allocation are different.

Comment: *But note that its scope is limited to the function in which it is declared, unlike dynamic allocation.* you are mixing lexical scope and storage duration.